# Drag & Drop Html5 `UL`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just made a script in which I drag and drop an unordered list.

Here is my example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6hqnz37/)):

Javascript:

```
var dragSrcEl=null;

function handleDragStart(e){
    this.style.opacity=0.4; // this / e.target is the source node.
    //Calling e.dataTransfer.setData(format, data) will set the object's content to the mimetype and data payload passed as arguments.
    dragSrcEl=this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

function handleDragOver(e){
    if(e.preventDefault){
        e.preventDefault();// Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect='move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e){
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(e){
    // this / e.target is the previous hover target.
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDrop(e){
    //this //e.target is current target element
    if(e.stopPropagation){
        e.stopPropagation; //stops the browser from redirecting
    }
    // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
    if(dragSrcEl!=this){
        // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML=this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML=e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }
    //see the section on the DataTransfer
    return false;
}

var cols=document.querySelectorAll('#apps_list .column');
function handleDragEnd(e){
    //this /e.target is the source node;
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col){
        col.classList.remove('over');
    });
}

[].forEach.call(cols, function(col){
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
    col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

CSS:

```
/* Prevent the text contents of draggable elements from being selectable. */
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
/** apps box **/
div.apps_box{
    /*margin: 0 1em;*/
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*top: 10em;*/
    right: .6em;
}
div.apps_box > ul#apps_list{
    /*height: 100%;*/
    width: 100% !important;
}
div.apps_box > ul#apps_list > li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #009ae1;
    margin: .1em;
    position: relative;
    cursor: move;
}
div.apps_box > ul#apps_list > li > span{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#apps_list > li > span > p{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 125px;
    position: relative;
    left:.2em;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    /** transition to make it fadeout after 1s **/
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    /** animation after mouse out **/
    -webkit-animation: animeitback 2s;
    -moz-animation: animeitback 2s;
    animation: animeitback 2s;
    /** animation fill **/
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
ul#apps_list > li > span > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #ddd;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
div.apps_box ul#apps_list .over{
    border: 2px dashed #000;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="apps_box">
    <ul id="apps_list" class="menu apps_list">
        <!-- row one -->
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Skype</a>
                <p>Skype is and app to chat with your friends</p>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Gmail</a>
                <p>Never let your news away get to know</p>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">VoiceMail</a>
                <p>Make it live and give it a life</p>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <p>Make it live and give it a life</p>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Viber</a>
                <p>Make it live and give it a life</p>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="column" draggable="true">
            <span>
                <a href="#">Phone</a>
                <p>Make it live and give it a life</p>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is when I finish the drag and drop, the event `handleDragEnd` doesn't seems to be working, and the opacity is stuck at `0.4`.

Comment: How do you have 200 points and not know how SO works??? :s

Post your code here.  External links are only supposed to be supplementary.  The question and answers should be totally self-contained.

Comment: I know the rules i wanted to make it easier the code is too long, sorry.

Comment: The code is never too long *if it is relevant to the problem*.

Comment: Okay thanks for the downvotes :D, but please provide a solution and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, changes:

Javascript:

```
function handleDragEnter(e){
    // this / e.target is the current hover target.
    this.classList.add('over');
    this.style.opacity=0.4; //adding the opacity here fixed the problem for the Drag enter
}

function handleDragEnd(e){
    //this /e.target is the source node;
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col){
        col.classList.remove('over');
        col.style.opacity = 1; //adding opacity here resets the opacity after the end of the drop
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
div.apps_box ul#apps_list .over{
    border: 2px dashed #000; //removing opacity from here helped to fix the problem, because adding it here is the same as adding it on the start handler.
}
```

Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

opacity stuck at 0.4 because you didn't changed it to 1
add `col.style.opacity = 1` in your `handleDragEnd` function like this

```
function handleDragEnd(e){
    //this /e.target is the source node;
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col){
        col.classList.remove('over');
        col.style.opacity = 1; // reset opacity here
    });
}
```

Comment: I did it but didn't work, it's like the handleDragEnd not working.

Comment: it works at the first time and then the opacity stays `1` then when you drag and drop the opacity of the current hover `li` don't change to `0.4`

Comment: can you elaborate what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: This is a bit of overkill.  You only need 1 line adding to the dragend event handler - `dragSrcEl.style.opacity = 1;`